# How does B(t) of a bezier curve move when P1/P2 move along tangent?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, bezier

When P1 changes from (0,4) to (0,2), Q1(t=0.5) and Q2(t=0.6) move 0.75 and 0.576 respectively. How can I calculate for any B(t) the distance it moves when P1 or P2 move along (Start--P1) or (P2--End) respectively?

[image]

Comment: You want to ask this over on http://math.stackexchange.com instead, although they might tell you to take some paper, draw out the curve with coordinates represented by symbols, and then simply write out the result of the De Casteljau linear interpolations with the difference you're applying to one of the coordinates. When you do, also make sure to give the other three points actual coordinates. Not unimportant. And finally, http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#moulding covers some of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write Bezier curve expression:

```
B(t) = P0 * (1-t)^3 + P1 * 3 * t * (1-t)^2 + P2 * 3 * t^2 * (1-t) + P3 * t^3
```

Let's P1' is new position of P1 control point. Only the second term will be changed, so

```
DeltaB(t) = B'(t) - B(t) = (P1' - P1) * 3 * t * (1-t)^2
```

if P1' lies on P0-P1, then

```
P1' = P0 + (P1 - P0) * u
DeltaB(t) =  (P0 + (P1 - P0) * u - P1) * 3 * t * (1-t)^2 = 
             (P0 - P1) * (1 - u) * 3 * t * (1-t)^2
```

For your example data

```
u = 0.5
(P0 - P1) * (1 - u) = (0, -2)   // (x,y) components of vector
DeltaB(0.5) = (0, -2 * 3 * 0.5 * 0.25) = (0, -0.75)
DeltaB(0.6) = (0, -2 * 3 * 0.6 * 0.4 * 0.4) = (0, -0.576)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something... In the image P2 is (3,4). When P2 e.g. is (2,4) and you move P1 to (0,2) Q1(t=0.5) still moves 0.75. That is why I think there is a simpler and faster way to calculate this than simply pluging in a new value for P1. The ratio seems to be the same for every curve. At least right now I think that when t=0.5 and you move P1 or P2 1 unit along (Start--P1) or (P2--End) Q1 moves unit/2.666 in the same direction... But I am reading Mike's article now...

Comment: `Q1 moves unit/2.66` - yes, look at my 2nd formula: deltaQ1 = deltaP1 * 3/8 (for t=0.5)

Comment: Indeed, super helpful. I knew it cannot be difficult, but I am always too blind to see those simple things. Thank you!